# Copy or move with combining source and destination path to avoid long path repeated

Tags: linux, unix, copy, move, cp

I need to edit many python files. When I about to start editing a file, I just create a copy of the file and will compare to this copy after I am finished editing and save changes to original file.

So I tend to work from one fixed location/path and edit/copy files in different paths by using their absolute path. I end up providing complete path for source file and complete path for destination file.

How can I use unix cp command which avoids mentioning path twice when both files are to be in same directory/path.

1. I have tried the traditional copy command: cp source-file target-file. But I had to repeat the path twice. For example:

   ```
   cp /main/dept_1/class_2/get_list.py /main/dept_1/class_2/copy_get_list.py
   ```
2. There is a different way to try this but I forgot exact syntax, but it goes this way:

   ```
   cp /main/dept_1/class_2/get_list.py[copy_get_list.py]
   ```

I expect to mention the path only once and be able to provide source and destination file names in copy (cp) command.

```
$home:ls /main/dept_1/class_2/

get_list.py

$home:cp /main/dept_1/class_2/get_list.py[copy_get_list.py]
```

I get error:   "cp: missing destination file operand after"

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces:

```
cp /main/dept_1/class_2/{,copy_}get_list.py
```

When you have a brace list in a word, the word is repeated with each list element replacing the brace list.